# Login with self-signed PGP/GPG cert. without security key

Tags: authentication, pgp, smartcard

Is there a way I can use a PGP certificate to login on my computer, but without a smartcard? I have multiple self made certificates for document encryption and also a state issued one for legal signing (and gov website login)

I've been looking all over the internet and can't find a card writer, only readers (ID, NIE, Passport, etc) used for web sign-in...

I assume there must be a way around that?